# Insert array contents into a string

Tags: php, string, arrays

I am trying to insert the contents of an array in to a string using PHP.
My array ($array1) looks like this:

```
Array1  
    (  
       [0] => http://www.example.com/1  
       [1] => http://www.example.com/2  

    )
```

I want to insert both links in to a coma separated string, so I can then insert it in to a database field.

I tried this:

```
foreach ($array1 as $name => $value) {
          $string1 .= $value . ",";
          }
  echo $string1;
```

Which does work, but I am doing this twice in my code for another array that I also want in a separate string ($string2)

```
    Array2  
    (  
       [0] => http://www.example.com/3  
       [1] => http://www.example.com/4  
    )
```

When I echo $string1 I get the correct output
`http://www.example.com/1,http://www.example.com/2`

But $string2 becomes this:
`http://www.example.com/1,http://www.example.com/2,http://www.example.com/3,http://www.example.com/4`

This happens even if I use different variable names in the foreach loop above.

Someone else also suggested I try this:

```
$string1 = implode(',' , $array1);
```

But I'm not getting any output.

Any help as to how to solve this, or any different approach is greatly appreciated!

Comment: To get ouptut, you need to echo, print, etc, $string1 (see my answer below). The code you show, just sets $string1 to a certain value, but it doesn't display that value.

Comment: Yes, I was echoing it but got no output because I was using the wrong variable name :/  I need to get off the computer for a while.Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There's a PHP function called [`implode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) for this exact purpose.

```
$csv = implode(',', $array);

echo $csv; //blah,blah,blah,blah
```

Comment: Implode, mentioned in OP. Looks like he expected it to output something.

Comment: heh, this said `explode` before. Knew I should have kept quiet for 5 more minutes ;)

Answer (score 1):

`implode` should work fine. It's won't give you any output unless you `echo` or otherwise output the result, of course.

Comment: I'm echoing of course after the implode, still no output though

Comment: argh just noticed why I got no output after implode. I was using the wrong variable name. Thanks!

Comment: Heh. Posting code helps... just make sure you read it while you're posting; you may find you don't need to ask anything after getting a fresh look at it. Sounds silly but it's happened to me more than once, now I just paste a scaled down copy into another buffer and take a fresh look at it.

Comment: Yes, this is a small script I'm writing to learn programming. Extracting the code from the rest of the script definitely helps. Also, getting up for a while from the computer helps too hehe.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> $array1 = array("http://www.example.com/1", "http://www.example.com/2");
>   $array2 = array("http://www.example.com/3", "http://www.example.com/4");
>   echo implode(", ", array_merge($array1,$array2));

**Output:**

> `http://www.example.com/1, http://www.example.com/2, http://www.example.com/3, http://www.example.com/4`